# Why is "courseName" not being checked and saved in the linq query?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

I'm trying to get pass some problems with my code.After I have redone my Entity Framework,I'm trying to save the details from a registration form.I'm using LINQ queries and my syntax is like this:

```
  public void SaveTeacher(object param)
    {

        using (DatabaseStudentsEntitiesLastStand db = new DatabaseStudentsEntitiesLastStand())
        {
            Cours c = new Cours();//this is the Cours table in the db
            c.education = education;//here I'm passing the value from the db to the value from VM.
            RegisterTeacher t = new RegisterTeacher();//this is another table in db where most of the info from registration is stored

            if (isChecked == true || c.courseName != null)
            {
                t.CourseName = c.courseName;//this is the courseName which belongs to courses,but I also have a column in RegisterTeacher for it

            }
            t.SNTeacher = SNTeacher;
            t.UserName = _UserName;
            t.pwd = pwd;
            t.fullName = fullName;


            db.RegisterTeachers.Attach(t);
            db.Courses.Attach(c);
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                foreach (var entityValidationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in entityValidationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Property:" + validationError.PropertyName + "Error:" + validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }//I'm trying to see the exceptions that I have in case something is not properly bonded(unfortunately no error)
```

This is the binding with the View for the button:

```
     <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"  
     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="517,98.4,0,0" Grid.Row="2" 
     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" Height="40"/>
```

And finally,passing the method to the delegatecommand:

```
  public RegisterTeacherViewModel()
    {
        mergeCommand = new DelegateCommand(CreateCrazy);
        saveCommand = new DelegateCommand(SaveTeacher);
        IsChecked = true;

    }

    private DelegateCommand saveCommand;
    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand
    {
        get { return saveCommand; }
        set
        {
            if (saveCommand != value)
            {
                saveCommand = value;
                NotifyOnPropertyChange("SaveCommand");
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know why is not working but maybe someone here can explain it to me.I have also tried to the simple query syntax and without any luck.It simply won't do with what I have...
Last but not least,I have established the datacontext in xaml.cs:

```
   public partial class Register : Window
{
    RegisterTeacherViewModel regTeacher;
    Object obj = new object();
    public Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        regTeacher = new RegisterTeacherViewModel();
        this.DataContext = regTeacher;
        cbxCourses.ItemsSource = regTeacher.GetByEducation();
        //coursesList.ItemsSource = regTeacher.GetByEducation();
        //regTeacher.CreateCrazy(ShowCourse);
    }
```

The rest of the xaml is as follows:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:RegisterTeacherViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid Margin="20,20,3.6,28.4">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label  Content="Register" 
            Foreground="White" 
            FontSize="25" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            Margin="179,0,175.6,0.4"/>

    <Separator>
    </Separator>

    <Label  Content="SN:" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,13.2,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Label  Content="Username:&#xD;&#xA;" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10,63.6,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="-0.833,-0.208"/>

    <Label  Content="Password:" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10,111.6,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    <Label  Content="Full 
            name:&#xD;&#xA;" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="10,158.2,0,0"
            Grid.Row="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.651,-0.415"/>

    <Label  Content="Courses teaching:&#xD;&#xA;" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="0,229.2,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

    <TextBox    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Name="SerialNr" 
                Height="23" 
                Margin="126,13.6,0,0"
                Grid.Row="1" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="{Binding SerialNT}" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="248" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <TextBox    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                Name="UsernameTeacher" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="23"
                Margin="126,63.6,0,0" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="{Binding UserName}" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="248"/>

    <PasswordBox    Name="passwordBox" 
                    mm:PasswordHelper.BindPassword="true"
                    mm:PasswordHelper.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Pwd, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    PasswordChar="*" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27"
                    Margin="126,111.2,0,0" 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="248"/>

    <TextBox    HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                Name="fullName" 
                Height="23" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap"  
                Text="{Binding FullName}" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="248" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                Margin="126,158.6,0,0" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

    <ComboBox   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                DataContextChanged="cbxCourses_DataContextChanged" 
                Text="{Binding Education}" 
                x:Name="cbxCourses" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Education}" 
                Margin="126,229.2,0,0" 
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                DisplayMemberPath="education"  
                Width="228" 
                Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="https://www.frostburg.edu/fsu/assets/Image/dept/educ/education_sign_resized.jpg" Height="20"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="Program"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>-->

    </ComboBox>//

    <button Content="Submit" 
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="517,98.4,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="110" 
            Height="40"/>

    <Button Content="Cancel"  
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="361,98.4,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="111"
            Height="40"/>

    <ListBox    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Name="coursesList" Height="240"   
                Margin="418,13.2,0,0" 
                Grid.Row="1" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="225"
                Grid.RowSpan="2"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>//here I have a listbox where I have a checkbox with the name of the courses the user wishes to check
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox   x:Name="CheckBoxCourses" 
                            Click="CheckBoxCourses_Click"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            Command="{Binding CheckCommand,Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Content="{Binding Path=courseName,Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Margin="0"/>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Button Content="Show courses:" 
            Name="ShowCourse"  
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=cbxCourses,Path=SelectedValue}" 
            Command="{Binding MergeCommand}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="163,61.4,0,0" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="137" 
            Height="35"/>

</Grid>//this is a button that shows the courses in the listbox after the program was selected
```

Comment: Show us the rest of the xaml

Comment: What do you mean by not working, is there an exception, is nothing happening when you click the button ?

Comment: @Matt Beldon Now I have edited my question with the full xaml file :)

Comment: @Usama nothing happens when I click the "Submit" button and it should display at least an error that the username or password is not correct,or that the fields are empty,instead it doesn't do anything

Comment: Set some breakpoints, see where the code actually goes.

Comment: Ok,i'll do this now I forgot about the breaking points,thank you!

Comment: @Henk Holterman ok,I did that and I have noticed that everything is fine,the new values are stored except for one which is courseName,because it depends on the checkbox and I can't seem to make it actually save the value.Except all that,the button is not working but it breaks when click it,so it's correctly bounded but even so,it won't store anything until my courseName will not appear as being checked.

Comment: So it does reach the SaveChanges() line? Add a `catch(Exception e){}` block after the catch you already have, and put a breakpoint in there. Also, describe "won't store anything" in detail.

Comment: @Henk Holterman so my "Submit" button breaks,the values are updated except for the courseName but it doesn't catch any exception,that's why I'm confused.It's like there's no binding at all when it comes to my button...I click the button at the end of the registration and when it breaks the only value left outside is the courseName which I don't know how to make it store the value(it's a checkbox and I have tried all the binding possible for it but without any luck).Except for that,no error that my fields are empty,no error that my courseName field is not set,usually sth should have been shown.